# One way cryptographic hashing of a number ensuring each result is unique

Tags: c++, encryption, hash

Is there a good algorithm for this? after an amount of searching around I haven't been able to find any conclusive answers.

Basically in a system which collects various bits of data about its users, each user is identified by a 64 bit unique Id. this Id is used as a primary key to a data set which may include any amount of data collected from this user. as is, this works fine as the Id's are already unique, but for legal reasons I need to hash the Id's in a way that I cannot link them back to the actual person. but at the same time needing to guarantee the uniqueness of the ID.

Obviously with the values being unique it would be possible to reverse engineer the algorithm used. but I'm not so sure that it being 100% unbreakable is so much of an issue here rather than making it so there isn't an easy way of reversing it

thanks

Comment: what you want is perfect hash function, the one that maps all members of input set to distinct members of another fixed length set. this is impossible.

Comment: @Andrey: I think that the input set and the result set have the same size, making a perfect hash perfectly possible.

Comment: Is this for credit card compliance?  I think you need to be much more specific about the rules, and also to describe who should not be able to reverse what mapping when they are in procession of which bits of data.

Comment: @DeadMG you might be right, but hash also should be irreversible.

Comment: @Andrey: I don't believe that a perfect hash is necessarily reversible in reality.

Comment: Hi, no its not for credit card compliance, its for collection of player data in a game

Comment: Basically, this 2^64 -> 2^64 mapping is an encryption function and it can be reversed, knowing the key.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For each ID generate a unique random ID and store it as part of the users information.

Then you can get from an ID to hash. The reverse is computationally possible (as you must scan the whole key space) but excessively hard and time consuming.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason why Unique ID needs to be the primary key? May be you could use some other primary key(Hash of the id) and store a encrypted primary user name which is encrypted using a known key.

As far as i know a hash value cannot be reversed

Comment: Unique id is the only unique info relating to a user, a username can be whatever the user chooses at any time and can change, as it is simply a display name.